# Django check if username starts with a special character and change it to authenticate with changed username

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Here's my custom auth backend. I want to check if username starts with a certain character and change this character to the new string or character.

```
class PhoneAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if username.startswith('8'):
                username[0].replace('+7')
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I tried:

```
class PhoneAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            bad_prefix = '8'
            good_prefix = '+7'
            if username.startswith(bad_prefix):
                username = good_prefix + username[len(bad_prefix):]
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

It doesn't work.

If I use this code it doesn't work too:

```
            if username.startswith(bad_prefix):
                new_username = good_prefix + username[len(bad_prefix):]
            user = User.objects.get(new_username=username)
```

**Solution:**

```
class PhoneAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            bad_prefix = '8'
            good_prefix = '+7'
            if username.startswith(bad_prefix):
                username = good_prefix + username[len(bad_prefix):]
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: What is your actual question / Issue?

Comment: I don't know how to implement what I want. This code doesn't work.

Comment: You need to give more info about what you've done - how are you even using this class?

Comment: I'm making a custom auth backend to handle feature mentioned above. I already have a backend to use the email instead of the username. I don't really understand how to check user's authentication input, change it and log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) it like that. Slicing string will be better.

```
>>> username = '8username'
>>> bad_prefix = '8'
>>> good_prefix = '+7'
>>> if username.startswith(bad_prefix): username = good_prefix + username[len(bad_prefix):]
>>> username
'+7username'
```

Comment: When you run `user.check_password(password)` user still has old username and it's not a good place to change it on the fly. You should probably change user username when it's created.

Comment: I want to let user log in with different types of writing phone number (with +7 or +1 in US, with 8 instead of +7, with 7 without + and without first digit at all)

Comment: then you should probably store the are code in one column and raw mobile number in another column or don't allow to change it all and always use the full number without doing what you're doing here.

Comment: You need to change the username before you call `User.objects.get(username=username)`